# Parsing Json as an Array of values ont objects or arrays

Tags: java, android, json

i have this model of  Json :

```
{
   "conditions":[
      "Offre non cumulable avec les promotions internes de playland",
      "Le centre ferme le lundi",
      "R\u00e9servation \u00e0 l'avance au 0661977474",
      "Les mineurs doivent remplir l'autorisation parentale sur le site www.playland.ma",
      "Valable sur pr\u00e9sentation d'une carte d'identit\u00e9 avec le bon",
      "Le forfait inclut les \u00e9quipements, les protections, le remplissage gaz et l'assurance",
      "Offre valable 1 mois du 1 Mars au 31 mars 2012"
   ]
}
```

and i need to parse it and put in in one String but i can't do that because the code that i'm using, parse only the first value in this Array and this is the code:

```
JSONArray c = deals.getJSONArray(condition);
            for(int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++){
                 String Precision = c.getString(i);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Gson which can opearte on Objects in java and convert object to json and vice-verse.

Link for Gson is -

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may help you.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponseString);

JSONObject arrObject = jObject.getJSONArray("Tagname");

for (int i = 0, len = arrObject.length(); i < len; i++) 
{
    JSONObject json = arrObject.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(json.getString("value1").toString());
    System.out.println(json.getString("value2").toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It is working fine at my end.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String json = "[\"Offrenoncumulableaveclespromotionsinternesdeplayland\",\"Lecentrefermelelundi\",\"Réservationàl'avanceau0661977474\",\"Lesmineursdoiventremplirl'autorisationparentalesurlesitewww.playland.ma\",\"Valablesurprésentationd'unecarted'identitéaveclebon\",\"Leforfaitinclutleséquipements,lesprotections,leremplissagegazetl'assurance\",\"Offrevalable1moisdu1Marsau31mars2012\"]";
        try
        {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

            for (int i = 0, len = array.length(); i < len; i++)
            {
                Log.i("info", array.getString(i));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thanx for your solution but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-Vipul shah was correct.

```
package com.ap.test;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StestActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    String json = "[\"Offrenoncumulableaveclespromotionsinternesdeplayland\",\"Lecentrefermelelundi\",\"Réservationàl'avanceau0661977474\",\"Lesmineursdoiventremplirl'autorisationparentalesurlesitewww.playland.ma\",\"Valablesurprésentationd'unecarted'identitéaveclebon\",\"Leforfaitinclutleséquipements,lesprotections,leremplissagegazetl'assurance\",\"Offrevalable1moisdu1Marsau31mars2012\"]";
    try
    {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i = 0, len = array.length(); i < len; i++)
        {
            Log.i("info", array.getString(i));

            sb.append(array.getString(i));

        }

        TextView sname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_activity_lat);
        sname.setText(sb.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```